# strange behavior of Contains() in a list of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a list of arrays and I need to verify if an arrays exists in the list. Like this:

```
Guid guid1 = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid guid2 = Guid.NewGuid();

List<Guid[]> listOfArrays = new List<Guid[]>();

listOfArrays.Add(new[] { guid1, guid2});

if (listOfArrays.Contains(new[] { guid1, guid2 }))
  Console.WriteLine(@"List of Array contains guid1 and guid2");
else
  Console.WriteLine(@"List of Array does not contains guid1 and guid2");

Console.ReadKey();
```

The output is:

> List of Array does not contains guid1 and guid2

However, if I use a list of Tuple instead of Array, everything works as I expect

```
Guid guid1 = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid guid2 = Guid.NewGuid();

List<Tuple<Guid, Guid>> listOfTuples = new List<Tuple<Guid, Guid>>();

listOfTuples.Add(new Tuple<Guid, Guid>(guid1, guid2));

if (listOfTuples.Contains(new Tuple<Guid, Guid>(guid1, guid2)))
   Console.WriteLine(@"List of Tuple contains guid1 and guid2");
else
   Console.WriteLine(@"List of Tuple does not contains guid1 and guid2");

Console.ReadKey();
```

The output is:

> List of Tuple contains guid1 and guid2

So my question is: Why this happen? Arrays and Tuples are reference type, shouldn't they have a similar equality comparison? If I want to use Arrays how can I do a "contains" that works in my situation?

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are compared by reference, so it does not work.

Tuples [override `Equals()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,169) to compare by value, so it works.

Comment: Thank you! But if I want use arrays, is there an elegant way to do that?

Comment: You can make your own `EqualityComparer<T[]>` and pass that.